# ping local network with netduino (C#)

Tags: c#, networking, ping, netduino

I need to ping different objects on my network with an netduino plus

any suggestions on what code would work best

Im trying to use using System.Net.NetworkInformation; but I don't have that library available to me (constraint of netduino framework?)

suggestions?

Comment: Do you have system.net.sockets available? You could ping that way.

Comment: do you have access to check something like the following? if you are using .NET framework I would think that you do `IPAddress address = GetIpFromHost(ref host);` read this article also do a google search it's so much easier and faster [Ping a Hostname on Network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689728/ping-a-hostname-on-the-network)

Comment: Its not a full .net framework. Its a stripped down version made to work on that micro controller.

Comment: Anon what is a striped down version..? the netduino..? state your comment appropriately so it makes more sense

Comment: It uses the .net MICRO framework.   Here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in Netduino project, but meanwhile someone created a library for Netduino which pings host. You can download ICMP library for Netduino here:
http://www.blake-foster.com/projects/ICMPPing.zip

More information on this code is here:
http://www.blake-foster.com/project.php?p=44

Comment: See here: http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/2208-ping-a-host-on-the-network/#entry15985

Answer (score 1):

I might have the solution for you:

http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/2208-ping-a-host-on-the-network/page-2

I've started fiddling with the code to make it do what I want, but the work done by the others actually does ping resources on the network.